# Prediction After One-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am trying with a sample dataFrame :

```
data = [['Alex','USA',0],['Bob','India',1],['Clarke','SriLanka',0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Country','Traget'])
```

Now from here, I used get_dummies to convert string column to an integer:

```
column_names=['Name','Country']  

one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df[column_names])
```

After conversion the columns are:
Age,Name_Alex,Name_Bob,Name_Clarke,Country_India,Country_SriLanka,Country_USA

#### Slicing the data.

```
x=df[["Name_Alex","Name_Bob","Name_Clarke","Country_India","Country_SriLanka","Country_USA"]].values  

y=df['Age'].values
```

#### Splitting the dataset in train and test

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=float(0.5),random_state=0)
```

#### Logistic Regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression()

logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Now, model is trained.

For prediction let say i want to predict the "target" by giving "Name" and "Country".
Like : ["Alex","USA"].

#### Prediction.

If I used this:

```
logreg.predict([["Alex","USA"]).
```

obviously it will not work.

#### Question1) How to test the prediction after applying one-hot encoding during training?

#### Question2) How to do prediction on a sample csv file which contains only "Name" and "Country"?

Comment: First, you should only post one question per thread. Second, your question is best suited for [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your model expects array inputs that correspond to `["Name_Alex","Name_Bob","Name_Clarke","Country_India","Country_SriLanka","Country_USA"]`. You will have to read your sample csv file and then shape it into an array in this shape, then call `logreg.predict(my_array)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use sklearn label encoders and one hot encoder packages instead of pd.get_dummies.

Once you initialise label encoder and one hot encoder per feature then save it somewhere so that when you want to do prediction on the data you can easily import saved label encoders and one hot encoders and encode your features again.

This way you are encoding your features again in the same way as you did while making training set.

Below is the code which I use for saving encoders:

```
labelencoder_dict = {}
onehotencoder_dict = {}
X_train = None
for i in range(0, X.shape[1]):
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    labelencoder_dict[i] = label_encoder
    feature = label_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,i])
    feature = feature.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    feature = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(feature)
    onehotencoder_dict[i] = onehot_encoder
    if X_train is None:
      X_train = feature
    else:
      X_train = np.concatenate((X_train, feature), axis=1)
```

Now I save this onehotencoder_dict and label encoder_dict and use it later for encoding.

```
def getEncoded(test_data,labelencoder_dict,onehotencoder_dict):
    test_encoded_x = None
    for i in range(0,test_data.shape[1]):
        label_encoder =  labelencoder_dict[i]
        feature = label_encoder.transform(test_data[:,i])
        feature = feature.reshape(test_data.shape[0], 1)
        onehot_encoder = onehotencoder_dict[i]
        feature = onehot_encoder.transform(feature)
        if test_encoded_x is None:
          test_encoded_x = feature
        else:
          test_encoded_x = np.concatenate((test_encoded_x, feature), axis=1)
  return test_encoded_x
```

Comment: Though this may work, I'd suggest to leverage the [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline) capabilities of sklearn. With the pipeline object, you can access also the parameters of every estimator and transformer in the pipeline.

Comment: I tried the above solution, but getting TypeError: unhashable type. At     "feature = label_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,i])".

Comment: I think you are not passing correct type of X as input.In my case I am converting the columns of pandas to arrays like this.    X = training_data[['feature1','feature2']].values and X = X.astype('str')

Comment: Great !!. Worked for me

Comment: Also note that you no longer need to use `LabelEncoder` before `OneHotEncoder`; the latter can be applied directly to string data.  Also, the `OneHotEncoder` can be applied to multiple columns at once, so there's no need to loop and manually save a dict.  +1 for the pipeline suggestion from @Quickbeam2k1.

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is giving TypeError, Use the below code which is updated using iloc.

```html
labelencoder_dict = {}
onehotencoder_dict = {}
X_train = None
for i in range(0, X.shape[1]):
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    labelencoder_dict[i] = label_encoder
    feature = label_encoder.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,i])
    feature = feature.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    feature = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(feature)
    onehotencoder_dict[i] = onehot_encoder
    if X_train is None:
        X_train = feature
    else:
        X_train = np.concatenate((X_train, feature), axis=1)
        
def getEncoded(test_data,labelencoder_dict,onehotencoder_dict):
    test_encoded_x = None
    for i in range(0,test_data.shape[1]):
        label_encoder =  labelencoder_dict[i]
        feature = label_encoder.transform(test_data.iloc[:,i])
        feature = feature.reshape(test_data.shape[0], 1)
        onehot_encoder = onehotencoder_dict[i]
        feature = onehot_encoder.transform(feature)
        if test_encoded_x is None:
            test_encoded_x = feature
        else:
            test_encoded_x = np.concatenate((test_encoded_x, feature), axis=1)
    return test_encoded_x
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).